# How can I find files with a full date in the file name and compare them to similar files?

Tags: c#, regex

Basically I have a directory of DWG files stored in a **List** that I need to search through and find files with the same Well Name but newest date in the File name.  Examples of file names are as follows:

```
Smith 08-14 #3-14H11 FINAL 02-05-2011.dwg
Scroggins 07-14 3-14 SDWD FINAL 10-28-2009.dwg
Smith 08-14 #3-14H11 FINAL 03-11-2011.dwg
Russel 10-15 #4-33H21 FINAL 10-07-2009.dwg
Scroggins 07-14 3-14 SDWD FINAL 11-29-2010.dwg
```

Notice after Smith there is a number 08-14, that is not the date.  The date I need to somehow compare to similar files is at the end of the File Name.  So for instance out of `Smith 08-14 #3-14H11 FINAL 02-05-2011.dwg` and `Smith 08-14 #3-14H11 FINAL 03-11-2011.dwg`, I would need to remove `Smith 08-14 #3-14H11 FINAL 02-05-2011.dwg` from my List because the other File with same Well name has a newer date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file names are in some kind of `List<String>` or you can use them as that.

make a small class to store information for each file

```
public class WellFile
{
   public DateTime FileDate { get; set; }
   public String WellName { get; set; }
   public String OriginalFile {get; set; }
   public WellFile(String FileName)
   {
      var fileHeader = FileName.Split('.').First().Split(' ').ToList();
      WellName = fileHeader.First();
      FileDate = DateTime.Parse(fileHeader.Last());
      OriginalFile = FileName;
   }

}
```

then using this class and your list of files

```
var ConvertedFileList = YourFileList.Select(x => new WellFile(x));
var NewestWellFile = ConvertedFileList.GroupBy(x => x.WellName)
                                      .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(x => x.FileDate).First().OriginalFile).ToList();
```

I haven't tested it but that should work for you

---

Working Example Program

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Foo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var wellList = new List<String>() {"Smith 08-14 #3-14H11 FINAL 02-05-2011.dwg",
                                           "Scroggins 07-14 3-14 SDWD FINAL 10-28-2009.dwg",
                                           "Smith 08-14 #3-14H11 FINAL 03-11-2011.dwg",
                                           "Russel 10-15 #4-33H21 FINAL 10-07-2009.dwg",
                                            "Scroggins 07-14 3-14 SDWD FINAL 11-29-2010.dwg"}; 
        var ConvertedFileList = wellList.Select(x => new WellFile(x));
        var NewestWellFile = ConvertedFileList.GroupBy(x => x.WellName)
                                      .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(x =>                              x.FileDate).First().OriginalFile).ToList();
        NewestWellFile.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class WellFile
{
   public DateTime FileDate { get; set; }
   public String WellName { get; set; }
   public String OriginalFile {get; set; }
   public WellFile(String FileName)
   {
      var fileHeader = FileName.Split('.').First().Split(' ').ToList();
      WellName = fileHeader.First();
      FileDate = DateTime.Parse(fileHeader.Last());
      OriginalFile = FileName;
   }

}
```

---

Comment: @msarchet- This is great msarchet..  If I wanted to include an IF statement that disregarded files that had a "_1" or "_2" before it parses the date out, where could I put that?  Occassionally, I may have a file like Smith 08-14 #3-14H11 FINAL 02-05-2011_1.dwg and I just want to skip those files and focus on the ones that just end something like 02-05-2011.dwg.  This definitely helps though..

Comment: @Joshua, the easiest way would be to check the strings before you filter them. Something like `var ConvertedFileList = wellList.Where(x => IsValidFileString(x)).Select(x => new WellFile(x));

Answer (score 1):

Make an data table and to break the file name into various components:

`Smith 08-14 #3-14H11 FINAL 02-05-2011.dwg` becomes

```
Name = 'Smith'
Code1 = '08-14 #3-14H11'
Revision =  'FINAL'
Date = '02-05-2011'
```

For example, take the last 14 characters of the file name `02-05-2011.dwg` and then removing the `.dwg` to make it `02-05-2011`.

Now you will sort by (Name, Date) then then just use the ones that match your criteria.

Comment: @ Raj-  Hi Raj, so would I use the substring method to break up the file name into those different sections?